# Where does mongodb store database in ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb

I want to take backup of a database in the mongodb. I found the command from documentation

```
mongodump --dbpath /data/db/ --out /data/backup/
```

But I see there is no any directory called "/data/" in my machine? But I can see the database in mongo shell:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> show dbs;
ihtx    0.203125GB
local   0.078125GB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea to know where the configuration is kept:

```
$ cat /etc/mongod.conf
# mongod.conf

# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
# e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

But in`/var/lib/mongodb` as it says there.

The standard installation procedure is here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks! I found the location as in `/var/lib/mongodb`. But could not find `/etc/mongod.conf`. even `locate mongod.conf` displays nothing!

Comment: @LaxmikantGurnalkar That is the standard layout for Ubuntu At least it is if you installed from a package, as the linked documentation explains. Use `ps aux | grep mongod` to see what options mongod was started with. It may not be using a config file on your system for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works. Could you please answer my next question.
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370107/which-is-my-database-in-mongodb`