# Which is my database in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, dump, mongodump

Next question in reference with previous one [Where does mongodb store databse in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369671/where-does-mongodb-store-databse-in-ubuntu)

```
$ cd /var/lib/mongodb/
$ ls
ihtx.0  ihtx.1  ihtx.ns  journal  local.0  local.ns  mongod.lock
```

Here, I can see `ihtx.0  ihtx.1  ihtx.ns` three files with the same name. Here which one is mydatabase which I usually see in mongo shell?
which one  should I dump ?

Tried each, getting following error :

```
$ mongodump --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ihtx.XX --out /home/user/Desktop/

If you are running a mongod on the same path you should connect to that instead of direct data file access

Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 dbexit: 
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: This is a fresh installation. There is no database except for the "local" which is for internal use. You seem to be learning. Your questions would be better suited here: http://superuser.com/

Comment: is you db path is set?? have you installed MongoDB sevices???

Comment: @Hardik: I'm not sure how to set the db path. and I don't do anything direct to the mongod. even I don't need that. This time I just need to dump my database. I use `erlang  and chicagoboss`. which automatically do all db transactions like create db, add collections, insert, update, delete data etc.

Comment: You were told at the beginning. Your question is "off-topic" for this forum. This forum is for "Programming" questions. You were also told **there is no** database. And that you have clearly not inserted any data. Ask you questions on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/). Better yet, read the manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/

Comment: @NeilLunn: I never said that my database is empty. and I have lots of data so that I want to dump before truncate. I'll  ask my question on superuser.com. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command will work for you
If your dbpath is set or you mongoDB service is Running
here ihtx denotes your dbname

```
$ mongodump -d ihtx --out /home/user/Desktop/intxDB
```

Comment: @LaxmikantGurnalkar From the first comment. There is **no** database here. It's all empty.

Comment: @NeilLunn : I can see the file name "ihtx" which is my database name. I can see my data in mongo shell db.
I can see three collections under mongo:
`> show collections;
ancestors 
inheritance_tax_forms 
inheritance_tax`

Comment: @LaxmikantGurnalkar
 How you can use MongoDB Sevices? 
IS you environment variable set??
Is you MongoDB Service is running??
You can access you mongoDB in your mongo-shell??

Comment: @Hardik: Nope, I'm running above command from terminal. not from mongo shell. Should I do that?

Comment: no, I want to know you can able to connect with your MongoDB??

Comment: @Hardik: Yes, I can connect MongoDB

Comment: ok then exit from mongoshell and then type
 $ mongodump -d your_database_name --out /home/user/Desktop/intxDB

Comment: @Hardik: Hangon please

Comment: @Hardik: Working now, my server was running under a screen. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

ihtx.0,ihtx.1,ihtx,ns represent the database `ihtx`.

The .0 .1 etc. files are the data files themselves.
 MongoDB names the first data file .0, the next .1, etc. The first file mongod allocates is 64 megabytes, the next 128 megabytes, and so on, up to 2 gigabytes, at which point all subsequent files are 2 gigabytes.

The ".ns" files are namespace files. Each collection and index would count as a namespace. Each namespace is 628 bytes, the .ns file is 16MB by default.

Now in your question, mongod instance is not able to remove fs lock(as you can see in the error).

```
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 [tools] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Mar 13 11:17:21.123 dbexit: really exiting now
```

As in your code, **dbpath** is **/var/lib/mongodb**, so When you are starting mongo instance, use --dbpath parameter as given :

```
mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
```

So first run following command:

```
mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb --repair
```

After that run following :

```
mongodump --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb -d ihtx --out /home/user/Desktop/intxDB
```

Comment: :Thank you, I'm getting error on `--repair` , 

`Thu Mar 13 12:29:32.759 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
`

Comment: updated the answer. Since you are using `/var/lib/mongodb` as dbpath, sp put that value in your command. Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

For your first question 'Which is my database file?', please refer the link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/

It clearly mentions that, 
"MongoDB preallocates data files to a particular size, in part to prevent file system fragmentation. MongoDB names the first data file .0, the next .1, etc."

And for the error which you are getting while taking dump,
Remove the --dbpath option and then try.

You either export from a running server, or from the files (if the
server isn't running, or locked), not both.

Comment: Thanks for the `MongoDB names summarisation`. But even removing --dbpath its not working. I'm doing this on my local machine not on server. Even I tried like: 
`$sudo service mongodb stop
$ mongodump --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb -d ihtx --out ` But same error occurred